# SQL Server can't import from generated script - syntax error near command '''

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am using a `.sql` file that was generated in SQL Server for SQL Server 2012 in order to build and populate a database on another server, also SQL Server 2012.

When I try to execute the query file using `sqlcmd` we get an error for what appears to be a single quote issue.

The error is:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Syntax error at line 45632 near command ''' in file 'db_main.sql'.

The insert command is:

```
INSERT [dbo].[SharedFields] ([Id], [ItemId], [FieldId], [Value], [Created], [Updated], [DAC_Index]) VALUES (N'jjjjjjjjjjjjjj', N'kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk', N'llllllllllllllllllll', N'<p>ItemIdPlaceholder</p>', CAST(N'2016-03-02T16:22:55.417' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-03-02T16:22:55.417' AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[SharedFields] ([Id], [ItemId], [FieldId], [Value], [Created], [Updated], [DAC_Index]) 
VALUES (N'aaaaaaaaa', N'bbbbbbbbb', N'cccccccccc', N'</div>
<script>
(function ($) {
    $j(''.wp-post-image'').each(function () {
        var postImage = $j(this);
        if (postImage.attr(''src'').indexOf(''/~/icon/'') == 0 || postImage.attr(''src'').indexOf(window.IconsCacheFolder) == 0) {
          postImage.addClass(''smallIcon'');
        }
    });

  var langs = $(''.evaluateLanguage'');  //error occurs here!

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i) {
    var textToPrint = '''';
    var splitLang = $(langs[i]).text().split(''^'');
    for (var j = 0; j < splitLang.length; j++) {
      if (splitLang[j].split(''|'')[0] != '''') {
        textToPrint += "<a class=\"languageLink\" href=\"\" onclick=\"event.stopPropagation();scForm.getParentForm().postRequest('''','''','''',''contenteditor:launchtab(id=" + $j(''.idFilter'').eq(i).text() + ", la=" + splitLang[j].split(''|'')[0] + ", version=1)''); return false;\"><span class=\"languageSpan\">" + splitLang[j].split(''|'')[0] + "</span></a>";
      }
      langs.eq(i).html(textToPrint);
    }
  }
})(jQuery || $j)
</script>', CAST(N'2016-03-02T16:22:55.427' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-03-02T16:22:55.427' AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[SharedFields] ([Id], [ItemId], [FieldId], [Value], [Created], [Updated], [DAC_Index]) VALUES (N'eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee', N'ffffffffffff', N'gggggggggggggg', N'<div class="mainmargin" id="grid-content" style="position: relative; width: 100%;overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;">', CAST(N'2016-03-02T16:22:55.427' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-03-02T16:22:55.427' AS DateTime), NULL)
```

We have taken insert out and 'parsed' it in SQL Server 2012 and it parsed just fine - no error/completed successfully.

Our question is: why does the insert work fine by itself, but fails when it is part of the larger query?

The `.sql` file is 128 MB in size.

Comment: What comes right before, and right after, this insert command in the larger query?

Comment: Added the line of sql code before and after. Per Tab's request.  Thanks for looking at this Tab.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in any of the code that you posted.   The problem is probably somewhere else in the file.   I would start copying chunks of the file, pasting it in SSMS, and parsing or executing it until you find the error.

Comment: UPDATE: What I've tried today:  a) work with SQLCMD (2014) - didn't help, b) found and removed the INSERTS that contained the "var langs" assignment plus recreated the database so it was clean, ran the SQLCMD with the edited .sql file - that allowed everything to work. I then took the three inserts that I removed and executed a query in SSMS2014 to insert those three rows.  Worked fine. (I'm concerned about indexes that don't have those three entries). c) back to original file and put "GO" statements on each side of the problematic INSERTS - didn't work, same error as at first.

Comment: Final update, as I have to continue working on our project.  I tried to insert the three problematic INSERTS using both the SQLCMD and a query window in SSMS2014.  It failed using SQLCMD and worked fine a query window.  I have my database now, but really don't understand the reason for the error.

Comment: @LReeder14 your last finding may be treated as answer? it's not a perfect answer, but it's helpful enough before having a better answer.